# OpenCV Threshold Type

Tags: opencv

I have a question about OpenCV's example on Basic Thresholding as provided in the link below:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#goal

I am slowly beginning to understand the code and have tried out an example too. However I am confused about a part of the code regarding thresholding operations. How does the thresholding function know which threshold operation to use?

This is where it is called:

```
threshold( src_gray, dst, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value,threshold_type);
```

I get that the last parameter "threshold_type is how it knows which threshold operation to use(eg. binary, binary inverted, truncated etc.) However in the code, this is all that is assigned to threshold_type:

```
int threshold_type = 3
```

As it is only assigned an int value of 3. How does the Threshold function know what operation to give it? Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using numeric literals to call the method of OpenCV instead use the constant variable defined in the opencv namespace, However it won't create any difference in output, but it makes the code more readable, So deciphered set of inputs to the `cv::threshold()` method are:

```
THRESH_BINARY     = 0,
THRESH_BINARY_INV = 1,
THRESH_TRUNC      = 2,
THRESH_TOZERO     = 3, 
THRESH_TOZERO_INV = 4,
THRESH_MASK       = 7,
THRESH_OTSU       = 8,
THRESH_TRIANGLE   = 16
```

According to this table you are using `thresholdType == THRESH_TOZERO`